# Ruby not recognizing gets.chomp, I think?

Tags: ruby

I'm new to programming and started with Ruby through the Learn Ruby The Hard Way book. I'm on exercise 13 and am just fiddling around with utilizing ARGV and gets.chomp in the same script. My code is as follows:

```
first, second, third = ARGV

puts "Your first variable is: #{first}"
puts "Your second variable is: #{second}"
puts "Your third is: #{third}"

print "Was that so difficult?"
answer = gets.chomp
print answer
```

Obviously this isn't that difficult of a script, but when I run it it I keep getting this error: "ex13.rb:in 'gets': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - 'it then prints the first argv the user inputs when starting the script' (Errno::ENOENT) from ex13.rb:8:in 'gets' from ex13.rb:8:in  "

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

That [is what `gets` does](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Kernel.html#method-i-gets). Quoting: "(`gets`) Returns (and assigns to $_) the next line from the list of files in ARGV (or $*), or from standard input if no files are present on the command line."

You could use `$stdin.gets`, or make sure ARGV is empty: `ARGV.clear` before using `gets`.

Comment: I'm not understanding this totally, but the ARGV.clear before gets worked. I'm just trying to go through exactly like the book, and there was a "common student question" section after this exercise that said they couldn't combine ARGV and gets.chomp. The writers response was "Just slap two lines at the end of this script that uses gets.chomp to get something and then print it."   - any explanation to that? I'm just a little confused. And thank you for helping, I appreciate it.

Comment: Ruby the hard way is a direct translation of Python the hard way. In the next chapter they use $stdin.gets, without explanation. They also use Python's """, and don't use `print` on the prompt lines. It's all a bit sloppy.